# Python 2: How can i add a string to the '.txt' document?

Tags: python

I have a **'.txt'** document called **'new_data.txt'**. For now it's empty. But I have an **'if'** statement inside a **'for'** loop that cheaks if **'x'** even or not. If true i want **(x + ' is even!')** to be added to my **'new_data.txt'** document.

```
for x in range(1,101):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        # and here i want to put something that will add: x + ' is even!' to my 'new_data.txt' document.
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Why is this tagged [csv]?

Comment: Brush up on your file handling skills. This should be an easy thing to do. :)

Comment: `'w'` mode for starting from scratch, `'a'` mode for appending to the end of the file.

Answer (score 5):

To write to a file in Python, use the `with` statement and the `open` built-in:

```
# The "a" means to open the file in append mode.  Use a "w" to open it in write mode.
# Warning though: opening a file in write mode will erase everything in the file.
with open("/path/to/file", "a") as f:
    f.write("(x + ' is even!')")
```

The `with` statement takes care of closing the file after you are done with it.

Also, in your script, you could simplify it and do:

```
with open('/path/to/file','a') as file:
    for x in [y for y in range(1,101) if not y%2]:
        file.write(str(x)+' is even!\n')
```

This will take every even number between 1 and 101 and write it to the file in the format "x is even!".

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you normally write to a file in Python:

```
with open('new_data.txt', 'a') as output:
    output.write('something')
```

Now just add the `'something'` you want to write inside the `with` statement, in your case, that's the `for` loop.

Comment: This will not "add" to the file. Instead it will overwrite the pre-existing contents of the file. Use the `'a'` flag while opening

Comment: Opening the file in write mode will erase everything in the file.  Shouldn't it be append mode?

Comment: Guys: the question is a bit unclear, OP wishes to "add" something to an empty file but it can be that he just wants to "write" to it. I edited my answer, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file', 'a') as outfile:
    for x in range(1,101):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            outfile.write("%s is even\n" %i)
```